# Mako error on one system not replicated on another

Tags: mako

The Mako community website appears to be polluted and not viewed by anyone who cam provide technical help

Using mako=1.3.0

I run a template program under Linux (Mageia 9) and Windows 10 (2 machines). On one machine, there are no problems, on the other, I get an error:
C:\Python\nci> python nci.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\tmp\mako_modules\ncilb.html.py", line 69, in render_body
cell = context['cell']
~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\charm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-
packages\mako\runtime.py", line 106, in **getitem**
return builtins.**dict**[key]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: 'cell'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\nci\nci.py", line 99, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Python\nci\nci.py", line 90, in main
tmpl.render_context(ctx)
File "C:\Users\charm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\mako\template.py", line 455, in render_context
runtime._render_context(self, self.callable_, context, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\charm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\mako\runtime.py", line 916, in _render_context
_exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
File "C:\Users\charm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site- 
packages\mako\runtime.py", line 943, in _exec_template
callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\tmp\mako_modules\ncilb.html.py", line 71, in render_body
raise NameError("'cell' is not defined")
NameError: 'cell' is not defined
```

The template module is here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aEYIhTxNnKI05O4zIaIbuhjMrZ8T4N4F/view?usp=sharing

I welcome your help to solve this.
Graeme

Answer (score 0):

I would think that probably `strict_undefined=True` is set on one machine and not the other.

> **What happens if I reference a variable name that is not in the current context?** -
> The value you get back is a special value called `UNDEFINED`, or if
> the `strict_undefined=True` flag is used a `NameError` is raised. ...

Docs: [context-variables](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html#context-variables)